# Azure Data Explorer - Projecting columns using parameters

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying use the multi-select parameter to filter displayed columns on my dashboard. I have found multiple separate commands (things like bag-unpack, mv-expand, set_difference and so on), but I don't have enough experience to put them all together. Please help, I'm new.

I've tried Googling different solutions, but I don't know what I don't know, so keyword search hasn't proven fruitful. I wanted to ask the community at StackOverflow for their input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar project where I set up a parameter called _columnNames which is a dynamic list of column names in my table. I wanted to plot specified columns relative to time and this could be done using the following code:

```
{Table Name}
| project Time, pa = pack_all()
| project Time, cols = bag_remove_keys(pa, set_difference(bag_keys(pa), _columnNames))
| evaluate bag_unpack(cols)
```

where {Table Name} refers to the table name you ingested in Azure Data Explorer.
Hope this helps!